# Is there any other way to restrict USB storage?

Tags: linux, security, usb, removable-storage

I have been using `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` to restrict USB storage but all employees are given root permissions, so they are removing restriction very easily. What I'm looking for is is there any other way to restrict USB storage usage (which is more hard to undo)?

I'm using ubuntu12.04 LTS.

Comment: What are you trying to do? It sounds like the entire mentality is wrong.

Comment: I'm trying to restrict access to USB storage. And my mentality is securing all system from unwanted viruses.

Comment: Then don't give them root access. You want an eventuality that makes no sense.

Comment: They need root password for starting apache, mysql and sort of services.

Comment: @RubanSavvy Then, I wonder if break down all USB port. Or give `sudo` privileges for apache.

Comment: Hmm I'll try for sure.

Comment: Give them root access only to virtual machines.

Comment: [Epoxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoxy).

Comment: Root access == no restrictions.  That's the "by definition" point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where I worked we had a very similar situation and this might sound heavy handed but we literally filled the USB ports with epoxy.

Comment: Where can I get a cookbook for epoxy?

Comment: An offboard USB controller is cheap, so this will provide only a minor roadblock if they are determined.

Answer (score 3):

You are asking for the impossible.

Anyone who has the password to the superuser (`root`) account has full access to the entire system. `root` needs that sort of access to be able to administer the system. There is no user account more privileged than root in Linux.

Based on what you wrote in the comments, there are a few obvious alternatives:

1. Don't give the users root access. Rather, run the services they need in such a way that root access is not required. There's no reason why Apache has to listen on a privileged port, for example.
2. Don't give the users root access. Rather, give them `sudo` access to precisely the things that they need to be able to do.
3. Physically disable the relevant ports. For example, by filling them with [epoxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoxy). *Do note* however that an offboard USB controller is really quite cheap, so much the same as blacklisting USB storage modules, this will not provide much of a roadblock if they are determined.
4. Use virtualization. This might actually be a better approach *if* VMs allow them to do what they need to do, as with proper settings the VM guest is for all intents and purposes fully isolated from the host.

I would recommend **giving the users only the privileges they need. A well-configured `sudo` setup** and/or moving the relevant services to a configuration that does not require root privileges will allow them to perform the actions they actually need to do, without having all-out root access. Also, make sure to look over /etc/fstab while you're at it, check that `mount` and friends are what they should be, that there are no set[ug]id binaries that shouldn't be there, ... you get the idea. Removing root access from someone who wishes to retain it is not particularly trivial, especially if they have any reason to believe that you are about to do it.